# How to calculate camber for a balsa glider?

Tags: general-aviation

I am making a rubber powered balsa glider for a competition. I want to make the glider fly as long as possible. I've heard that a high camber means slower speed means more airtime. I want to make sure that the camber isn't too high, and I need to know what type of camber I should use. Also, I need to know if the horizontal and vertical stabilizer size is fine.

The dimensions of my glider include: 32cm fuselage, 7.8cm wing chord, 28cm wingspan, 5.5cm horizontal stabilizer chord, 11.5cm horizontal stabilizer span, 5cm vertical stabilizer height, and 5.5cm vertical stab width.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Are you optimising for flight duration or flight length ?

Comment: The problem here is that a catapult launched glider needs low camber during the launch and higher camber during the low-speed glide. Either you pick a compromise, or try to build a wing with flexible ribs that flattens out at speed (which is what the experts do).

Comment: Optimising for duration.  Optimising for distance traveled would have been phrased "as far as possible," not "as long as possible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Aviation SE, Samarth!

Flight duration depends not only on camber, but also launch speed, launch angle, mass, propeller diameter, propeller pitch, rubber quality, winding tightness, etc.  I assume that by "rubber powered glider" you mean rubber band powered for the first part of the flight, gliding thereafter.

Even if you somehow find optimal values for all the other parameters except for camber, it's still simplest -- and most trustworthy! -- to build several interchangeable wings for the glider, varying camber, and directly measuring flight duration with a stopwatch.